# Is there a way to warn remote computer of pending restart AND have my script wait for the restart to complete?

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to combine the "You will be logged off in x minutes" functionality of 'shutdown.exe", and the "-Wait -For PowerShell" functionality of the Restart-Computer cmdlet.

I have a script that requires a remote computer to restart. I'd like to warn the user of the remote computer that their computer will restart in 5 minutes. I would also like my script to wait until the restart completes before continuing forward.

Shutdown.exe has a great warning system and delay built in, but no great way to have the script wait for the reboot to complete. I've tried a loop that waits until Test-Connection is $true, but of course a computer returns a ping before it can accept PowerShell commands like Invoke-Command. I could slap a Start-Sleep on the end, but the time between ping and PowerShell accepting commands varies per computer.

Restart-Computer has a great "wait for PowerShell" feature, but there's no way to warn the user of the remote computer that their computer is about to restart. I've tried running the commands below, but the restart-computer cmdlet will throw an error if there's already a shutdown in progress.

```
shutdown /r /t 300 /m \\computer $system
restart-computer -computername $system -Force -Wait -For PowerShell -Timeout 300 -Delay 2
```

Comment: Why not run invoke-command on the computers you intend to restart to show the pending restart message with msg.exe? Then just run restart-computer as you have in the question. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName asdf -ScriptBlock { msg.exe * "Reboot soon" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try just sending the message just before your call to `Restart-Computer` using the `msg` command:

```
msg * /SERVER:$system /TIME:300 "Computer will be restarted in 5 minutes."
restart-computer -computername $system -Force -Wait -For PowerShell -Delay 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't say this is a complete answer to your question, but instead of `Test-NetConnection` (which only tests ping/TCP as you mentioned), [use `Test-WSMan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.wsman.management/test-wsman?view=powershell-6) which will test the protocol over which PowerShell Remoting operates (note other protocols are possible, but you're likely just using this one in your environment).